# Trying to print indvidual plots outside loop in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am breaking my data frames into 3 other data frames. I am iterating through each of them and plot histogram based on it. I am storing these plots into separate ones. However, outside the loop, I am able to print only the plot from the last iteration and not the first two. I am able to print all three plots inside the loop though. Here is my code:

```
catCust1 <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 0 & myData$meanVal <= 20),]
catCust2 <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 20 & myData$meanVal <= 40),]
catCust3 <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 40 & myData$meanVal <= 60),]

for(i in 1:3) {
  if(i == 1) {
    catCust <- catCust1
  } else if(i == 2) {
    catCust <- catCust2
  } else if(i == 3) {
    catCust <- catCust3
  } 

  catCust <- na.omit(catCust)
  numOrdersCatCust <- ddply(catCust, .(ORDERDATE), nrow)
  numOrdersCatCust$numDay <- 1:nrow(numOrdersCatCust)
  catCust$orderCount <- numOrdersCatCust[match(catCust$ORDERDATE, numOrdersCatCust$ORDERDATE), 2]
  catCust$numDay <- numOrdersCatCust[match(catCust$ORDERDATE, numOrdersCatCust$ORDERDATE), 3]
  setDT(catCust)[, uniqueCounter := .GRP, by = CUSTOMERID]
  apply(catCust, 2, function(x)length(unique(x)))
  threshold25catOne <- catCust[(catCust$uniqueCounter == as.integer(0.25 * max(uniqueCounter))), ]
  threshold25catOneVal <- threshold25catOne$numDay

  catCustPlot <- ggplot(data=catCust, aes(catCust$numDay)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, col="black", fill="white", alpha=0.1) +
    labs(x="Day Number (Since 01-09-2016)", y="Orders") +
    ggtitle("GRAPH TITLE") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = threshold25catOneVal[1], color="purple") +
    annotate("text", x = threshold25catOneVal[1]-7, y = max(catCust$orderCount) + 1000, angle = 0, label = threshold25catOneVal[1], vjust = 1.2, parse = TRUE)
  # ABLE TO PRINT DIFFERENT PLOTS HERE
  if(i == 1) {
    catCustPlot1 <- catCustPlot
    print(catCustPlot1)
  } else if(i == 2) {
    catCustPlot2 <- catCustPlot
    print(catCustPlot2)
  } else if(i == 3) {
    catCustPlot3 <- catCustPlot
    print(catCustPlot3)
  } 
}

# PRINTS ONLY catCustPlot3
print(catCustPlot1)
print(catCustPlot2)
print(catCustPlot3)
```

The other two plots gives me an error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

UPDATE: head(myData)

```
meanVal  sumVal    countCat
75.98  75.98000    (60,80]
36.37  80.55727    (80,100]
50.96  52.67500    (40,60]
15.33  15.33000    (0,20]
17.48  27.65000    (20,40]
51.35 101.64900    (100,1e+04]
```

Comment: Because your ```if``` will satisfy only one condition and then one outcome so one plot!

Comment: It is satisfying all the conditions across all the iterations. Also, when I replace catCustPlot with some number or character, it prints all the values correctly outside the loop. But it fails when I try to get a plot.

Comment: @trollster Can you please `head(myData)`

Comment: @PoGibas updated!

Comment: @trollster tried to debug, please see if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simplified you loop and stored `ggplot` objects to `resPlots` (no printing out). When loop finishes you can access/print them.

```
myData <- na.omit(myData)
resPlots <- list()
for(i in 1:3) {
    if (i == 1) {
        catCust <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 0 & myData$meanVal <= 20), ]
    } else if (i == 2) {
        catCust <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 20 & myData$meanVal <= 40), ]
    } else if (i == 3) {
        catCust <- myData[(myData$meanVal > 40 & myData$meanVal <= 60), ]
    } 

    numOrdersCatCust <- ddply(catCust, .(ORDERDATE), nrow)
    numOrdersCatCust$numDay <- 1:nrow(numOrdersCatCust)
    catCust$orderCount <- numOrdersCatCust[match(catCust$ORDERDATE, numOrdersCatCust$ORDERDATE), 2]
    catCust$numDay <- numOrdersCatCust[match(catCust$ORDERDATE, numOrdersCatCust$ORDERDATE), 3]
    setDT(catCust)[, uniqueCounter := .GRP, by = CUSTOMERID]
    apply(catCust, 2, function(x)length(unique(x)))
    threshold25catOne <- catCust[(catCust$uniqueCounter == as.integer(0.25 * max(uniqueCounter))), ]
    threshold25catOneVal <- threshold25catOne$numDay

    resPlots[[i]] <- ggplot(catCust, aes(catCust$numDay)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, col = "black", fill = "white", alpha = 0.1) +
        labs(x="Day Number (Since 01-09-2016)", y="Orders") +
        ggtitle("GRAPH TITLE") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = threshold25catOneVal[1], color="purple") +
        annotate("text", x = threshold25catOneVal[1]-7, y = max(catCust$orderCount) + 1000, angle = 0, label = threshold25catOneVal[1], vjust = 1.2, parse = TRUE)
}

# First plot    
resPlots[[1]]
```

Comment: Instead of `ggplot` do this: `resPlots[[i]] <- catCust`  and check if table is correct

Comment: Tried that as well, same problem.

Comment: Then it's your data problem, you have to look closer into it.